# Problem to Deploy Web Application .net core as Sub Application of .net 4.0 on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, .net-core, .net-4.0

I have a application Angular.js with backend .net 4.0 deployed on IIS 8 that use a URL domain of my company.

Now I createda new application using .net core  2.1 and i Would Like Deploy these application using the same domain url but using a diferent path for access a route like mydomainprincipal/myNewApp

This .net core application working well on Development enviroment but when I publish on IIS as a Sub Application, creating a new site into the main site and try access this application on browser it not load the site.js (it's returned 403) but show the menu (broken because not load site.js) if i trying access a view like mydomainprincipal/myNewApp/mycontroller/mypage this returned 403.

I tryed put the folder of the new application into the root of the main aplication.

Create a aplicationpool  for each application.

Config applicationpoll of .net core with "no manage code";

I Reviewed the folder permissions.

I Reviewed the web config of the child application (.net core)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
site.min.css:1
sit.min.js

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you review thre folder permission? Check the aps.net core application's identity permission? Besides, I suggest you could try to check your site.js's path by using F12 develop tool to make sure the site.js path is right.

Comment: I verified if the network service and system had a full control on folder, and the answer was true.

Comment: The path is correct but trow 403 forbiden error.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kind of the authencation mode you have used now? Form authencation, windows authencation or Anonymous authencation ?  I suggest you could re-check the IUSR and application pool permission to make sure you have set the enough perission for these two kinds of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved using "Location" configuration on a parent web config

A just put all configurations of my web config ( of main application) inner of the location tag as bellow:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">

// My Web config configurations.   

</location>
```